# Trying to find out which line something is in a file and applying it to something else

Tags: python, file

I'm very new to this so sorry if I'm doing it wrong.

I'm trying to make a create account/login system and I'm using two separate .txt files to store the usernames and passwords.

When the usernames are created, the passwords are added to the corresponding lines on the other file. Once I've verified that the username is correct, I am trying to work out which line the username is on in my file so that I can find the correct password for that username.

Could someone help me find a way to find the line that the username is on and use that to check if the password is the correct password for that particular username?

```
username = input("Please enter your username: ")
    with open("usernames.txt", "r") as loginfile:
        if (username + "\n") in loginfile.readlines():
            password = input("Please enter your password: ")
            with open("passwords.txt", "r") as loginfile:
                if (password + "\n") in loginfile.readlines():
                    print("Welcome!")
```

This works completely fine, but if I used this, then someone could type in a correct username and a correct password, but the password isn't the password that is linked to that username, even though it is a correct password.

It's hard to describe but I hope that makes sense!

Please help if you can!!!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the line number.  You could use the `index` method of a list to find which item matches.  (This will raise `ValueError` if none of them match.)  Then you can index the list of passwords (with newlines) on the line number of interest.

```
username = input("Please enter your username: ")
with open("usernames.txt", "r") as loginfile:
    try:
        line_number = loginfile.readlines().index(username + "\n")
    except ValueError:
        line_number = None

if line_number is not None:
    password = input("Please enter your password: ")
    with open("passwords.txt", "r") as loginfile:
        if (password + "\n") == loginfile.readlines()[line_number]:
            print("Welcome!")
```

Note that in reality you would probably still want to prompt for a password even if the username does not exist and therefore the login has no chance of succeeding, because otherwise you give away too much information to somebody who is trying a brute force attack (guessing usernames and passwords) by making it possible for them to know whether the username that they are trying is valid or not.  This could easily be achieved by moving the `password = input(...)` line to before the `if` block.